# I need to down size my jQuery Code it to repetitive

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need to down-size jQuery code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159096/i-need-to-down-size-jquery-code)

Yesterday I placed a jQuery code snipet that y developed and need a little help with, It works fine but, it’s just too long and repetitive, I do not mean disrespect to the grate programmers that tried to help me yesterday because there grate, but its almost sure I did not asked the right questions, one of theme suggested that the question needed to be asked here and so I am doing now.

OK, I have as you can see in the code, 12 tiles in a left div, those tiles are to be generated from a mySql database, and will show a thumbnail.. when clicking on a tile, the content on the right div will fade out and present the div corresponding to the clicked tile, the information on the appearing div is stored on a mySql db as well. Its working ok but. The code for the whole thing is just too big, and repetitive. It’s not a gallery and the icon on the tile probably has nothing to do with the content to de right.

Thanks to  `mrtsherman`, `jfriend00` and `elclanrs` for the help last night, I know it’s my fault for not asking the right question. 
Som, here is the code in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/tgcNd/6/

And below my Frankenstein of a code

```
jQuery(function($) {
function boton1(event)
{
$(".vitrina1").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina1").css("top","0");
$(".vitrina1").animate({"opacity":1,"top":0},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton2(event)
{
$(".vitrina2").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina2").css("top","-712px");
$(".vitrina2").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-712},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton3(event)
{
$(".vitrina3").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina3").css("top","-1424px");
$(".vitrina3").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-1424},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton4(event)
{
$(".vitrina4").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina4").css("top","-2136px");
$(".vitrina4").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-2136},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton5(event)
{
$(".vitrina5").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina5").css("top","-2848px");
$(".vitrina5").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-2848},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton6(event)
{
$(".vitrina6").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina6").css("top","-3560px");
$(".vitrina6").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-3560},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton7(event)
{
$(".vitrina7").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina7").css("top","-4272px");
$(".vitrina7").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-4272},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton8(event)
{
$(".vitrina8").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina8").css("top","-4984px");
$(".vitrina8").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-4984},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton9(event)
{
$(".vitrina9").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina9").css("top","-5696px");
$(".vitrina9").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-5696},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton10(event)
{
$(".vitrina10").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina10").css("top","-6408px");
$(".vitrina10").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-6408},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton11(event)
{
$(".vitrina11").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina11").css("top","-7120px");
$(".vitrina11").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-7120},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina12").animate({"top":7832},1, "linear", null);
}
function boton12(event)
{
$(".vitrina12").css("opacity","0");
$(".vitrina12").css("top","-7832px");
$(".vitrina12").animate({"opacity":1,"top":-7832},300, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina1").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina2").animate({"top":712},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina3").animate({"top":1424},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina4").animate({"top":2136},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina5").animate({"top":2848},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina6").animate({"top":3560},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina7").animate({"top":4272},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina8").animate({"top":4984},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina9").animate({"top":5696},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina10").animate({"top":6408},1, "linear", null);
$(".vitrina11").animate({"top":7120},1, "linear", null);
}
$('#btn1').bind('click', boton1);
$('#btn2').bind('click', boton2);
$('#btn3').bind('click', boton3);
$('#btn4').bind('click', boton4);
$('#btn5').bind('click', boton5);
$('#btn6').bind('click', boton6);
$('#btn7').bind('click', boton7);
$('#btn8').bind('click', boton8);
$('#btn9').bind('click', boton9);
$('#btn10').bind('click', boton10);
$('#btn11').bind('click', boton11);
$('#btn12').bind('click', boton12);
});
```

The HTML

```
<div id="contenedorPrimario">
<div id="botones">
<div class="boton" id="btn1"><a class="tooltip" rel="Contenedor 1"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen1.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn2"><a class="tooltip" rel="Cajón<br>Contenedor 2"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen2.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn3"><a class="tooltip" rel="Este es el<br>Cajón 3"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen3.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn4"><a class="tooltip" rel="Ejemplo de contenido<br>dentro del cajón<br>Contenedor 4"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen4.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn5"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen5.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn6"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen6.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn7"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen7.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn8"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen8.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn9"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen9.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn10"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen10.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn11"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen11.jpg"></a></div>
<div class="boton" id="btn12"><a class="tooltip" rel="Aqui texto"><img src="http://www.auviproducciones.com/more/imagenes/imagen12.jpg"></a></div>
</div>
<div id="aparador"> <!-- main right container -->
<div id="mercancia"> <!-- info Divs container this one scrolls uo and down if animation tyoe changes from fade to scroll -->
<div class="vitrina1">Hello this his window #1<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina2">Hello this his window #2<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina3">Hello this his window #3<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina4">window #4<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina5">window #5<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina6">window #6<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina7">window #7<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina8">window #8<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina9">window #9<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina10">window #10<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina11">window #11<br>with mySql content</div>
<div class="vitrina12">window #12<br>with mySql content</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Adn finally the CSS

```
#contenedorPrimario { position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:100%; background: url(../imagenes/fondo_index.jpg); width: 1100px; height: 800px;}
.clear {clear:both;}
/* Inicia Cajón Izquierdo */
#botones {position:absolute; width:450px; height: 592px; margin-left:3px; margin-right:20px;margin-top:50px;padding-bottom:4px;}
.boton {width:150px;height:142px;float:left;cursor: default;}
.boton img {width:150px;height:142px;}
#sociales { position: absolute; width:450px; height: 120px; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 620px; /*background: #FF3300; */}
/* Inicia Cajón Derecho */
#aparador {position:absolute; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 456px; width:641px;overflow: hidden; height:712px; background:#666; margin-right: 20px; }
#mercancia {position:absolute; width: 641px; height: 9324px; margin-top: 0px; visibility: visible; background: #fff; }
.vitrina1, .vitrina2, .vitrina3, .vitrina4, .vitrina5, .vitrina6, .vitrina7, .vitrina8, .vitrina9, .vitrina10, .vitrina11, .vitrina12 { position:relative; width:641px; height: 712px; }
.vitrina1 { /*background-color: #33CCCC;*/ background: #D2D2D2;}
.vitrina2 { background-color: #999900;}
.vitrina3 { background-color: #CC6600;}
.vitrina4 { background-color: #AA0000;}
.vitrina5 { background-color: #99CC33;}
.vitrina6 { background-color: #0066CC;}
.vitrina7 { background-color: #570699;}
.vitrina8 { background-color: #CC33CC;}
.vitrina9 { background-color: #02F965;}
.vitrina10 { background-color: #FFFF00;}
.vitrina11 { background-color: #C80461;}
.vitrina12 { background-color: #000066;}​
```

Comment: Please don't post the [same question twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159096/i-need-to-down-size-jquery-doce), and what was wrong with the answers you got [in your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159096/i-need-to-down-size-jquery-doce)?   You should probably post this on the [code review SE site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: Sometimes if it works, leave it alone. This code is very readable, and would not be too difficult for another person to read.

Comment: Sorry and Thanks, I read the rules but also followed the advice some else give me on the other post. Didn’t mean to be rude. And luckily on this post the question was solved by  Ilia G (Love this person).

Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem pretty trivial... See [my version](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/tgcNd/13/) of your code

```
$("#botones div.boton a").each(function(idx)
{
    $(this).click(function() 
    {
        $("#mercancia div").hide()
            .filter("div.vitrina" + (idx+1)).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Also note that I changed default style for `vitrina`s from `position:relative` to `display:none`

Comment: Oh my god, that is pure Genius... Thanks a lot, you are great, my respects to you, beautiful, it works... Yeees!  Thank you, and Thanks to everyone else interested in solving this my trivial puzzle... Love you man.

Answer (score 0):

It won't edit your code but you could use a [code compressor](http://javascriptcompressor.com/) to shrink your code so that your page loads faster. Otherwise, you could create a loop but you will still need arrays which won't really make the code much shorter.

Comment: Yes you are right but Ilia G just saved the day. Thanks for the link, I’m sure it will come in handy.